# Finding a short cut to "Connect To Network

Tags: windows-7, networking, powershell, shortcuts

Is it possible to create a shortcut for

`Network --> Properties-->Connect to a network`

in Windows 7?

`Connect to a network` is available in

`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center`

If no shortcut is available, can this be reached through PowerShell or some other way?

I have looked around the network menus, and cannot find a way to avoid walking through each menu.

Comment: You mean besides left-clicking on the Network icon in the system tray?

Comment: @MichaelFrank Just tried it, and that opens the same thing. I'd love to encapsulate `Connect to a network` either in a shell script or as a shortcut.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe NETSH can help. NETSH LAN Reconnect -or- NETSH WLAN Connect. There is also a network icon in the system tray.